# How to make the * wildcard work in Java url API

Tags: url, servlets, wildcard, servlet-filters

Good day!

I made a filter servlet and I am trying to not include the css and js. So I wrote this code:

```
if (url.equals("/login.jsp") || url.equals("/login") ||url.equals("/AddApplicantServlet") ||url.equals("css/*") || url.equals("js/*") ||url.equals("/index.jsp") {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
          ....
    }
```

My XML is

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filter.ServletFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

But on the above code.. the `url.equals("css/*")` and url.equals`("js/*")` doesnt work... It seems that using wildcard on the URLs are not possible.

Is there any other way to code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.equals` method checks for strict equality.

You should call [`startsWith`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).
You can also call [`matches`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) to test it against a regex.